# Get array with the position of a repeated char in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, char, comparison

The input is an string and a char, i.e:

```
string stInput = "An string with multiple spaces";
char charInput = ' ';
```

The output should be an array of integers, i.e:

```
int[] output = CharPositions(stInput, charInput);
// output = {2, 9, 14, 23};
```

Here is my guess:

```
int[] CharPositions(string stInput, char charInput)
{
    List<int> output = new List<int>();
    int i = stInput.IndexOf(charInput, 0);
    while(i > -1)
    {
        output.Add(i);
        i = stInput.IndexOf(charInput, i + 1);
    }
    output.Add(i);
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Is there any way more efficient to do it?

Comment: have you tried anything or do you just expect an answer?

Comment: @Delta I've tried with string.IndexOfAny() but it does the opposite. After googling with someone with the same problem I've found nothing.

Comment: Pretty hard to guess what an inefficient way could possibly look like.

Comment: You need to show more effort. What have you tried? This reads like "pls send teh codez"

Comment: I've written a simple loop in my notebook but doesn't look very nice. I'm going to copy it as you ask.

Comment: well put that code in here and we can tell you if its efficient, or we could use it to write a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public int[] CharPositions(string input, char match)
{
    return Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape(match.ToString()))
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Index)
               .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You should do `Regex.Escape(match.ToString())`

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to get much more efficient than a loop with `IndexOf` inside of it.

```
IEnumerable<int> CharPositions(string input, char match)
{
    int i = input.IndexOf(match, 0);
    while(i > -1)
    {
        yield return i;
        i = input.IndexOf(match, i + 1);
    }
}
```

You can call `.ToArray()` on the above method's results if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the string:

```
static IEnumerable<int> CharPositions(string input, char match)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (input[i] == match)
            yield return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] IndicesOf(this string self, char match)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(self))
    return new int[0];

  var indices = new List<int>();

  for (var i = 0; i < self.Length; i++)
  {
    if (self[i] == match)
      indices.Add(i);
  }

  return indices.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> CharPositions(string input, char match)
{
   return input
         .Select((x, idx) => new { x, idx })
         .Where(c => c.x == match)
         .Select(c => c.idx);
}
```

Or, use a simple `for` loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> CharPositions(string input, char match)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
       if (input[i] == match)
             yield return i;
    }
}
```